# Mergin/Input -- trouble synching from tablet to server

Tags: qgis, mergin-maps

I have 4 Android tablets running one project on Mergin Maps. I have been able to synch 2/4 tablets with no issues. However, the other 2 tablets seem to synch locally and then the data does not show up on the project/server. I verified that they are logged in and the usernames have writing capability.

Is there anything obvious that I am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

If you experience any issues with syncing data, best to look at diagnostic logs. Logs contain detailed information about the application run, so there may be hints for you on how to troubleshoot the problem.

To access the diagnostic log in Mergin Maps Input:

1. Tap More and open Settings
2. Select Diagnostic log to display the log

Also it is good to check if the Mergin Maps Input is on latest version.

Comment: Great idea -- will do this now.